# Why is there different results when calculating a double sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider:
$$
\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& \ldots\\
1/2 & -1 & 0 & 0& 0& \ldots\\
1/4 & 1/2 & -1 & 0& 0& \ldots\\
1/8 & 1/4 & 1/2 & -1& 0& \ldots\\
1/16&1/8 & 1/4 & 1/2 & -1& \ldots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{matrix}
$$

When I calculate the sum of each column first, I got $0,0,0\ldots$ then sum them up the answer should be $0$. But when I calculate the sum of each row, I got $-1, -1/2, -1/4, -1/8,\ldots$, then the sum will be $-2$. Why is there different results when I calculate the sum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum is not absolutely convergent (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series) so we can make the sum equal whatever we want.

With divergent series the way that we order the series may change the sum. As @DuAravis said the series can be written as
\begin{align*}
S_n &=(-1) +(\frac{1}{2} -1) +(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2} -1)+(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2} -1) +\ldots=-2 \quad (1)
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
S_n &=(-1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8} +\ldots) +\ldots (0-1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8} +\ldots) +\ldots=0 \quad (2)
\end{align*}
but we can also rearrange the matrix as follows,
$$
\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& \ldots\\
1/2 & -1 & 0 & 0& 0& \ldots\\
1/2 & 1/4 & -1 & 0& 0& \ldots\\
1/2 & 1/4 & 1/8 & -1& 0& \ldots\\
1/2 &1/4 & 1/8 & 1/16 & -1& \ldots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{matrix}
$$
now if we sum the columns we get $\infty$.

Also, we need to be careful about multiplying. For example, if multiply each term by $x$. Then by (2) this shouldn't change the total sum,
\begin{align*}
S_n &=x \times (-1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8} +\ldots) +\ldots x \times (0-1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8} +\ldots) +\ldots=x \times 0=0
\end{align*}
but now if we use (1),
\begin{align*}
S_n &=x \times (-1) +x \times (\frac{1}{2} -1) +x \times (\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2} -1)+(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2} -1) +\ldots=-2x \quad (1)
\end{align*}
The problem I think is that you're working with $\infty$'s so when you manipulate the sum it's like adding, subtracting, or multiplying by $\infty$. Here are two famous examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series.
Here are some links on mathexchange [Sum of divergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735190/sum-of-divergent-series) and [Sum of infinite divergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59512/sum-of-infinite-divergent-series)

Comment: I think I got the idea of the convergence but I don't understand why can it be whatever we want, could you please elaborate more?